# Windows 10 taskbar: Deactivate show on mouse hover and "events"

Tags: windows-10, taskbar

Windows taskbar pops up every time some "Event" occures or if the mouse is in the area which is quite too sensitive.

Is it possible to hide taskbar completely and only show it when you press the windows <kbd>[image]</kbd> key (settings, third party tools)?